# Force using specific filter text on a content type

Tags: 7, entities

How can I limit the text filter type upon a textarea field.

Example (the needed result would be like this) :

- Authuser is a role that can change the value of textarea_1 and textarea_2 on contentTypeA
- Authuser can't change the 'text filter' value of textarea_1 (it's on filtered HTML)
- Authuser can change the 'text filter' value of textarea_2 with only (Plain text or ckEditor(WYSIWYG))

Is that possible? if yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using format permissions in combination with the [Better Formats](https://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module should allow you to do what you are trying to do.

The [Better Formats](https://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module allows you to set allowed and default text formats per field - so you can set different allowed formats for both of your fields.